# Re-Theme Private Message Function

Tags: privatemsg

I would like to rewrite the original function code for the Private messages block module. The original code displays a text message for no messages or messages in the inbox. I would like to change it to an image but am no where near on the right track.  Here is the coded that I am trying to change

```
 /**
 * Theme a block which displays the number of new messages a user has.
 */
function theme_privatemsg_new_block($count) {
  $count = $count['count'];
  if ($count == 0) {
    $text = t('0 Messages');
  }
  else {
    $text = format_plural($count, 'You have a new message!',
                        'You have @count new messages!');
  }

  return l($text, 'messages', array('attributes' => array('id' => 'privatemsg-new-link')));
}
```

I was trying the following replacement:

```
/**
 * Theme a block which displays the number of new messages a user has.
 */
function theme_privatemsg_new_block($count) {
  $count = $count['count'];
  if ($count == 0) {
    /*$text = t('0 Messages');*/
    $text = l('<img src="messages.png" height="40"/>);
  }
  else {
    /*$text = format_plural($count, 'You have a new message!',
                        'You have @count new messages!');*/
    $text = l('<img src="messages.png" height="40"/>');                   
  }

  return l($text, 'messages', array('attributes' => array('id' => 'privatemsg-new-link')));
}
```

I suspect there are issues with the fact that it is designated as a text string instead of code that should be rendered.  What do you think?

Using PHP I am trying:

```
/**
 * Theme a block which displays the number of new messages a user has.
 */
function theme_privatemsg_new_block($count) {
  $count = $count['count'];
  if ($count == 0) {
    /*$text = t('0 Messages');*/
    $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'eternal'));
    $text = '<img src="' . $base_path . '/' . $theme_path . '/images/messages.png" width="50"/>';
  }
  else {
    /*$text = format_plural($count, 'You have a new message!',
                        'You have @count new messages!');*/
    $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'eternal'));                    
    $text = '<img src="' . $base_path . '/' . $theme_path . '/images/messages.png" width="50"/>';                   
  }

  return l($text, 'messages', array('attributes' => array('id' => 'privatemsg-new-link'), 'html' => TRUE));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$text = l('<img src="messages.png" height="40"/>);` looks wrong. "l" is function to create links, i guess thats what is failing here. Try to remove it and leave just `$text = '<img src="messages.png" height="40"/>';`.

[For reference on "l" see drupal api page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) - please note that there is also 'HTML' parametr in "l" function that you should set to true, since you are passing HTLM code in $text to that returning "l".

> 'html' (default FALSE): Whether $text is HTML or just plain-text. For example, to make an image tag into a link, this must be set to TRUE, or you will see the escaped HTML image tag. $text is not sanitized if 'html' is TRUE. The calling function must ensure that $text is already safe.

Comment: I had tried that before but it just literally prints the html code instead of rendering the image

Comment: Did you modified return? `return l($text, 'messages', array('attributes' => array('id' => 'privatemsg-new-link'), 'html' => TRUE));` ?

Comment: nope, looks like the html true was the final key.  Thank you very much

Comment: One more question, can I make it php also?

Comment: You can put any PHP code inside your `theme_privatemsg_new_block` function that will output text/HTML to `$text` variable (instead of static string '<img src="messages.png" height="40"/>' you have there now).

Comment: I tried '$text = '<img src="<?php print($base_path.'/'.drupal_get_path('theme', 'eternal')); ?>/messages.png" width="50"/>'; '   However as you see, the quotes and ticks are going to mess up the code, in addition to the <php flags.  What do you think?  Reason is because if I place the images inside of the PM mpdule directory, the path to the image is still incorrect, so if I just put it in the theme directory, at least I know the absolute path.  I prefer to use it in the PM directory but the path is not working.

Comment: You are already writing PHP in module code, so including <?php ?> tag is causing errors. You should write something like this instead: `$theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'eternal')); $text = '<img src="' . $base_path . '/' . $theme_path . '/messages.png" width="50"/>';` (check if those paths are returning what you expect, i dont know if they are relative or absolute)

Comment: no, something wrong with the text$ declaration $theme_path. I added the new php above

Comment: checked those paths, try this `$theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'eternal'); $text = '<img src="' . base_path() . $theme_path . '/messages.png" width="50"/>';`

Comment: ahh mannnn, I should have caught that extra parentheses. THanks for that. I was looking at that theme path line before and had not used it yet.